# Undefined method in my show page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like I'm close but something is amiss. I'm getting undefined method 'each' in my show page.

My show has the following:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Name:</dt>
  <dd><%= @region.name %></dd>
  <dt>Location</dt>
  <dd><%= @region.each do |region| %>
        <%= region.location.name %>
       <% end %> </dd>
</dl>
```

In my Regions Controller I have the following:

```
class Admin::RegionsController < Admin::ApplicationController
 belongs_to_app :regions
 add_breadcrumb 'Regions', :admin_regions_path
 before_action :load_region, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @regions = Region.ordered.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @regions = @regions.search(params[:search]) if params[:search]
  respond_with @regions
end

def show
  respond_with @region
end

def new
  @region = Region.new
  respond_with @region
end

def create
  @region = Region.new(region_params)
  flash[:notice] = 'Region created successfully' if @region.save
  respond_with @region, location: admin_regions_path
end

def edit
  respond_with @region
end

def update
  flash[:notice] = 'Region updated successfully' if @region.update_attributes(region_params)
  respond_with @region, location: admin_regions_path
end

def destroy
  flash[:notice] = 'Region deleted successfully' if @region.destroy
  respond_with @region, location: admin_regions_path
end

private

def load_region
  @region = Region.find_by!(id: params[:id])
end

def region_params
  params.require(:region).permit(:name, location_ids:[])
end
end
```

I attempted to update my Locations Controller to have:

```
def show
 @region = Region.find(params[:region_d])
 @location = @region.location
end
```

I end up getting the exact same undefined method issue being presented. Am I missing something that's way too obvious that should allow me to pull on the location name for display?

Ultimately I just to see something like:

Region: One
Locations: Alpha, Beta, Gamma

Probably need to put in something that delineates between the values that are being generated as well but that's a different issue.

Comment: It does. Before action hitting load_region method that defines @region

Comment: Is region a Enumerable? If not then you cant use each on it.

Comment: @Jake: ah, indeed.

Comment: @rajbir: actually, module Enumerable doesn't have method `.each` :)

Comment: I should have said collection. My bad :)

Comment: For the future, when you get an exception, post the full exception message and not just a random bit from it. Sometimes it's necessary to post the exception trace too, but full message is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your view to

```
<dd>
  <%= @region.locations.each do |location| %>
    <%= location.name %>
  <% end %> 
</dd>
```

@region is a single instance, not an array, so you can't use `each` on it

Answer (score 3):

> I'm getting undefined method 'each' in my show page
>
> [I set `@region` in my show method and] I end up getting the exact same undefined method issue being presented

Take a closer look at the error message. It is `undefined method each for #<Region:1234>:Region` (or something similar), isn't it?

Value of your `@region` is not a collection and thus doesn't know method `.each`. To avoid this error, call `.each` on a corresponding collection (*whatever that might be in your app. Seems to be `@region.locations`*)

Answer (score 1):

So Vasilisa gave the right answer to this particular instance and Sergio schooled me on what I missed/how it operates. But I wanted to post out an answer that I ultimately used that took Vasilisa's response a bit further to make the desired result that I posted about.

```
<dd>
  <%= @region.locations.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
</dd>
```

Comment: Yes, it is better option